# Reading in data from a USB port

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb

I’ll make this quick. I’m using windows 10, and I have a wired Xbox one controller.

I was wondering how I can read the raw data from the wired controller. I know there are ways to check for inputs (which button has been pressed, etc), but I’m only looking for raw data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the Linux driver and write a new one for Windows I guess...?

Comment: @DanielB is there not a feature in windows which allows you to see raw data coming from a USB port?

Comment: Well sure, you could try using USBPcap and Wireshark. That will get you USB as raw as it gets. Not sure if that’ll be helpful though. Maybe you should tell us about your actual problem.